# Unable to display pdf on android localhost

Tags: php, android, pdf, localhost

I've been using KSWEB's phpFileManager tool to host images on an android tablet for a while now and have tried to expand that capacity to .pdf files.  Unfortunately given that the file manager opens in a browser on an android, it is unable to view any pdfs.

Since this is local, using google docs doesn't work and when I try to view it in something like an alternative browser such as dolphin with a pdf viewer plugin, it displays a blue box with a question mark inside which apparently indicates that the file was unable to be found.

Here's the code that I'm using in the localhost for reference.

```
<HEAD>

<TITLE> Title Goes Here </TITLE>

<?php
$a = array();
$dir = 'fileNameInphpFileManagerDirectory';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
        elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
        elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
        elseif (preg_match("/\.pdf$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
foreach ($a as $i) {
     echo "<img src='" . $dir . '/' . $i . "' />";
}
?>
```

Comment: That icon indicates a plugin could not be loaded. Is the plugin actually flash? Because Flash is deprecated for Android. It no longer works officially. You can try downloading and installing flash from here: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk

Comment: Thanks, i tried, but it still didn't work.  I'm beginning to suspect that dolphin's pdf viewer is either a clone of google docs's or google docs with a skin on it and thus can't access the file for the same reason.  

if it at all helps here are some images of what I see when I try to view the thing http://imgur.com/a/hOEku